How to turn SSI on on Nginx Unit?
Does Nginx Unit support SSI (Server-Side-Includes)?
How to turn SSI feature on? How to set flag when compiling?
Now our build is not aware of SSI, thats why we have technical message printed
"serverTime": "<!--#config timefmt='%s'--><!--# echo var='date_local'-->"


Nowadays SSI feature not supported
https://github.com/nginx/unit/discussions/1322
